# TelephonyManager.getCellLocation crashing asking for READ_PHONE_STATE permission in some devices

Tags: android, android-permissions

We use the method `getCellInfo` from `TelephonyManager` in our app and it's been working fine without any issues except for a very very few devices where it's crashing with the following message

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Requires READ_PHONE_STATE: Neither user 10215 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

However, the documentation doesn't say that we require this permission for invoking this method. Also, we're not asking for this permission at all. Has anyone faced this issue. I'm guessing that this might be a general problem with permissions itself? We're targeting sdk version 22, minSdkVersion is 15.

Answer (score 1):

My app has the same problem when using `TelephonyManager`. Its targetSdkVersion is 27 and minSdkVersion is 17.

According to the crashing report of my app from Google Play Console, the phones that have this SecurityException problem are Oppo, LG, Asus and Sony phones which have Android 5.0-5.1. After that, I ran my app on the emulator of Android Studio with Android 5.0 and 5.1. I found that it will crash because of not having `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.

Therefore, I think that this issue will happen to most devices with Android 5.0 or 5.1, nothing with the brands of the phone.

The solution is to add the following code to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
```

I set the `maxSdkVersion` of this permission to 22 because this SecurityException will not happen after Android 6.0, so this permission is not needed for the phones with Android 6.0 or newer.